# Cursor moves to top when refreshing list page grid

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

Fellow developers,
I have a custom list page, where a user can select few records, hit a button in Action pane that runs some logic in a class, and all that works fine. My problem is that the cursor does not stay at the same record but goes to the top of the grid. Sounds like a familiar issue?

I store the FormDataSource of the list page using args in the custom class that has all the logic.

I tried few things but none worked.

1. **formDataSource.research(true)**
   True parameter is supposed to retain the position after research does its job. I am guessing this should have been the most straightforward solution. List page query has 2 datasources joined using Outer join and my guess is research(true) works only with Inner joins.
2. **formDatasource.setPosition(position)**

   int position;
   position = formDatasource.getPosition();

   formDatasource.research();

   formDatasource.setPosition(position);

   I store the position using getPosition and set it again using setPosition. No use.
3. **formDataSource.findRecord()**

   currentRecord = formDatasource.cursor();

   recId = currentRecord.RecId;
   formDatasource.reread();

   formDatasource.research();
   formDatasource.findRecord(currentRecord);

   i use the ds.cursor() to get the current record and pass it to findRecord() after research(). No use.
4. **formDataSource.findValue()**

   currentRecord = formDatasource.cursor();

   recId = currentRecord.RecId;
   formDatasource.reread();

   formDatasource.research();
   formDatasource.findValue(fieldNum(Table, RecId), int642str(recId));

   i use the ds.cursor() to get the current record and recId and pass it to findValue() after research(). No use.

I debugged the above code and the cursor() method does get the current record and its recId. 
I have started to believe that it might be a limitation of list page, and praying that somebody proves me wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you also try by using the task macro and call the #taskF5 to refresh the form. This results same as clicking the refresh button on list pages. you can refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh812104.aspx for more details.

Comment: 'research' has an optional boolean parameter to retain the position in the grid.  For an excellent overview see http://kashperuk.blogspot.com.es/2010/03/tutorial-reread-refresh-research.html

Answer (score 2):

Use Method 3 but like this.

```
YourTable tmpTable;


currentRecord = formDatasource.cursor();

recId = currentRecord.RecId;
tmpTable = TmpTable::findByRecId(recId);
 formDatasource.reread();

formDatasource.research();
formDatasource.findRecord(tmpTable);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: //just set the recId of the tmpTable-Buffer:

JUW_tmpCostCalculation positionDummy;
;
positionDummy.recId = JUW_tmpCostCalculation.recid;
JUW_tmpCostCalculation_DS.research();
JUW_tmpCostCalculation_DS.findRecord(positionDummy);

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass "true" as a parameter for the research method.
salesLine_ds.research(true) works in my case, i.e. if I research the line, cursor stays on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

use the second method like this

```
int position;
position = formDatasource.getPosition();
//Make your update operations here
formDatasource.research(true);

formDatasource.setPosition(position);
```

It works for me.